# get values from MulitpleChoiceField

Tags: django, forms, validation

I'm struggling with something that seems quite simple to me so I apologize in advance if this seems a silly question. I am struggling to get the value submitted by a form using POST that has values that comes from a drop down list. The values are displayed from the django admin site, ie an admin user can add multiple values in the admin site and these values appear in a drop down list using a MulitpleChoiceField. (this way admins control the ip addresses that can be tested against)

In my models, I have the following configured.

```
from django.db import models

class ServerIpAddress(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


from platform.models import ServerIpAddress
```

In my form, I have the following configured.

```
serverip = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CloudStackIpAddress.objects.all(), 
           label='server IP to test')
```

When the form is submitted, I am collecting the cleaned data in my views.py

```
cd = form.cleaned_data
serverip = cd['serverip']
```

However when I review the value comes back as after the form has been submitted I get the following

```
 'serverip': <ServerIpAddress: 10.0.25.14>
```

I just need the ip address, in this case 10.0.25.14 (or it could be another value). The format I currently have is causing a problem further down the line as the script cannot determine what the IP address is as it currently reads .

Please can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serverip = cd['serverip'].name` should fix your problem.

Did you know that django already provides an [`IPAddressField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ipaddressfield)?

Comment: Thank you! I've played with the .name but in another way. This is how close I was 

serverip = cd['serverip']

t_serverip = serverip.name. 

I knew there was an ipaddress field but this way I can controll which IP addresses are displayed in teh MulipleChoiceField. Thanks again

Comment: Using the built-in IPAddressField wouldn't have changed how you used it with MultipleChoiceField.

Answer (score 1):

You have a ServerIpAddress instance - and according to your model, the value is stored in the `name` attribute. So if you just need to pass the value to some other function, you would do `serverip.name`.